# IJCADの.NETでのPlotter出力の結果

Tags: .net, ijcad

AutoCADのVBAではファイル出力やプロッタ出力時の結果が以下のように受け取れます。

```vba
bool ir;
GcadDocument AOBJ;
if( )// ファイル出力の場合
{
    ir = AOBJ.Plot.PlotToFile(@"C:\Temp\test.PLT");
}
else // PLOTER出力の場合
{
    ir = AOBJ.Plot.PlotToDevice();
}
```

上記部分を.NET（C#）に以下のURLの内容を元に変更していますが
成功か失敗かの結果を受け取る方法はないでしょうか？

[.NET - 現在のレイアウトを印刷する](https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/115000185522--NET-%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%8D%B0%E5%88%B7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Answer (score 0):

PlotReactorManagerクラスで、印刷関連のイベントを使用することができます。
印刷の最終的なステータスを取得できますので問題なく出力されたのか、出力がキャンセルされたのかなどのステータスを確認することができると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。PlotReactorManagerでは開始と終了とキャンセルは得られますが、エラーは得られませんでした。

Comment: IJCADの.NET APIでは、印刷する際に使用しているメソッドが、PlotEnginクラスの実際に印刷を実行しているのはPlotEngine.BeginDocumentメソッドです。

Comment: PlotReactorManagerクラスでイベントを有効にしたとき、BeginDocumentメソッドを実行して問題が発生しなかった場合は、BeginDocument→BeginPage→EndPage→EndDocumentと通知されますが、設定に問題があり印刷に失敗した場合は、BeginPageとEndPageは通知されません。
例外をキャッチする以外でエラーを取得するには、BeginPageとEndPageが通知されたかどうかで判断できると思います。